# Phpmyadmin like inputs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change some tables to dynamically changeable tables (click on the cell to modify the content - Essentially you click on the cell and it converts the content to a textbox to be modified when you click off it submits the data to a php statement to be saved).
I am not very familiar with jquery or ajax so this is going to be difficult.

currently I am just trying to achieve the first part (click and convert to a textbox - click off and convert back to text)

I found this elsewhere on stackoverflow

http://jsfiddle.net/NCHJB/3/

so ideally I would want to delete the

```
   <td><button>Edit</button></td>
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I would just put an input box there, and use css to remove all borders, background...etc.

Then when you focus on the input box, add a css class to it to restore the input-like css styles, and remove them when you lose focus (onblur)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pe47d/

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="something!" />
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
$('#test').focus( function() {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
}).blur( function() {
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
    // Do stuff here if you want... like submitting data to server or something
});
```

CSS

```
#test {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: none;
}

#test.focus {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**UPDATE** to your requirements..

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S99My/

HTML

```
<table id="table">
    <tr><td><span class="text">Something</span><input type="text" class="hidden" name="somename" value="Something" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="text">Something</span><input type="text" class="hidden" name="somename" value="Something" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="text">Something</span><input type="text" class="hidden" name="somename" value="Something" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="text">Something</span><input type="text" class="hidden" name="somename" value="Something" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
jQuery( function($) {
    $('.text').click( function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings('input').show().focus();
    });

    $('#table input').blur( function() {
        // Save stuff here....
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings('.text').show();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: the problem with this is the user could still "tab" over

Comment: this is still not working - when you click off the textbox it is not changing the content in the span. otherwise amazing

Comment: That's what the 'save stuff here' comment is for :P I don't know what logic you want to run

Comment: Thanks so much i've changed this to work with bootstrap custom row fields , awesome !